# Escaping text in C++ to pass the data as JSON object

Tags: c++, json, serialization

I'm writing a node module in C++ that passes data back and forth using JSON objects.

For example, I'm reading this CSV line into C++:

```
// input.csv
description;This is a "text" containing all sorts of symbols: Ü€ễ張
```

The desired output should be a valid JSON object like this:

```
{
 "description": "This is a \"text\" containing all sorts of symbols: Ü€ễ張"
}
```

Example code on the C++ side is:

```
if(line[0] == "description") {
  std::string jsonObject = std::format("{{\"description\":\"{}\"}}", line[1]);
}
```

So while I have confirmed that the data is read correctly into C++ (I can write it back to a file and all characters are as they should be), there are two problems with the JSON:

1. The apostrophes are not being escaped, so the JSON is invalid.
2. The special characters are not displayed correctly.

While I can simply do a replacement for the apostrophes (`"` to `\"`), I'm assuming there are more cases for `1.` I need to be aware of that can mess up a string (e.g. backslashes).

So, how can I escape strings to pass them safely back and forth in my JSON objects? Is there an easy way to transform them into a 'safe' format?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use a proper JSON library such as nlohmann::json instead of `format`. Untested: `json::object{{"description", line[1]}}.dump()`. Of course what it does with your special characters is entirely dependent on how they were encoded on disk and read into a `std::string`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm actually using `rapidjson` to parse JSON from the frontend to `C++`. However, I could not figure out how to make it work. 

Also, how do I know the encoding of the `std::string` and how would I then convert it so something "safe"?

Comment: Is your csv in utf-8? (which are the hexa corresponding to `"Ü€ễ張"` (better to have only one at first)).

Comment: Edit your question with the note about rapidjson and the things you tried.

Comment: Nlohmann::json assumes std::string contain UTF-8-encoded strings. So if your file is already encoded as UTF-8 it will just work.